# Bash: How do you view text that has been "scrolled up too far" in the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, scrolling

I know there is a simple unix command that allows you to view things from the top and/or allows you to scroll indefinitely toward the top. Not sure what to call it, so it's difficult to google. Thanks to anyone who can explain how to do either one for me

Comment: Scrollback is a function of the terminal emulator bash runs in, not bash itself.  It would help if you posted which one you are using (`gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, `konsole`, `rxvt`, etc).  Pipe output to `less` or any similar pager if you want to be able to scroll up independent of what your terminal can do.

Comment: Lol thanks jw013. But I'm not even sure what terminal I am using! (currently I have ubuntu 11.04 installed on my computer, but I'm running it in 'classic mode' which I think using Gnome-3 instead of Unity...?)

Comment: Yes, 'less' was definitely what I was looking for! However, do you know how to go directly to the bottom in less? (for instance, if the information you are viewing is really really long)

Comment: Try pressing `G`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> is the binding for wandering the scrollback under the default terminal in recent Ubuntu releases.

Comment: I don't think that was quite it :(

Answer (score 3):

Terminal multiplexers `screen` or `tmux` both have this scrollback feature.

Comment: What about when you're in the installer of Arch?